# AJAX request on link click in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I am trying to start a PHP function in Wordpress on the click of a link. I've managed to do it using a form-submit, but I want to do it on a link click.

I've pulled together an AJAX request but it doesn't seem to work - any thoughts much appreciated.

HTML Link Code

```
<a href="#link_id"> Ajax Click </a>
```

Javascript Function

```
<script>

// Create a function to pick up the link click

$('#link_id').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault(); // prevent default behaviour of link click

    var data = {
        action: 'test_response_php', // This is the PHP function to call - note it must be hooked to AJAX
    };

    // Post to The Wordpress URL

    jQuery.post("<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>", data, function(response) {
        alert(response);
    });

});
```

PHP Function

```
function php_function() {
    echo 'Hello World';
    // Some interesting server side stuff

}

add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_test_response_php', 'php_function');
add_action('wp_ajax_test_response_php', 'php_function');
```

Comment: change this <a href="#link_id"> Ajax Click </a>  to <a id="#link_id" href = "#"> Ajax Click </a> #link_id should be an id not a href

Comment: Thanks Karthik. That doesn't seem to work either!

Comment: Any error in browser console when you clicked the link and jQuery starts running?

Comment: Any function that you're running from one of the `wp_ajax_` hooks should end in an `exit`

Comment: Thanks @jakeparis That's super helpful to know. Is it just any function which is hooked wp-ajax OR also any function which is called in that function too?

Comment: Any function that is hooked onto the `wp_ajax_` directly. It can do whatever else you want within there, but at the before the function ends, you should tell php to stop doing anything else with `exit`. Once you call exit, the php engine stops, so obviously you can only do that one time.

Comment: Thanks Jake - done!

Comment: plus 1, Nice solution, Thanks for asking the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your anchor tag like this:-

```
<a href="#" id="link_id"> Ajax Click </a>
```

You were missing id tag in anchor and you are running click event on id click.